# Populate sysrefcursor out parameter in Oracle package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle package that execute a procedure. It has a sysrefcursor out parameter. I need to populate this parameter with a select, but when I run the package gives error saying that there is no data. I already checked the select and returns information. Below my code

```
PROCEDURE PESQ_TB_EQUIPE_FISCALIZACAO(
    P_RECORDSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    V_CODE NUMBER;
    V_ERRM VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
    OPEN P_RECORDSET FOR
        SELECT E.COD_EQUIPE,
               E.EQUIPE,
               E.RESPONSAVEL,
               E.TEL_RESPONSAVEL,
               M.LAYER MUNICIPIO
          FROM TB_EQUIPE_FISCALIZACAO E
          JOIN G_CARTO_MUNICIPIOS M
            ON M.CODIGO = E.COD_CIDADE
         ORDER BY E.EQUIPE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        V_CODE := SQLCODE;
        V_ERRM := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 128);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_CODE || ' ' || V_ERRM);  
END;
```

My select returns:

```
cod_equipe equipe           responsavel tel_responsavel municipio
1          CONTROLE_SERVICO             (33)3456-9328   GOVERNADOR VALADARES
2          CORTE_RELIGACAO                              GOVERNADOR VALADARES
3          DISTRIBUICAO     Silvani                     GOVERNADOR VALADARES
4          FISCALIZACAO                                 GOVERNADOR VALADARES
5          HIDROMETRIA                  (33)3456-9870   GOVERNADOR VALADARES
6          LIGACAO          Cinthia                     GOVERNADOR VALADARES
7          RECOMPOSICAO                                 GOVERNADOR VALADARES
```

Comment: Are you sure Your select statement is returning data? Or Post your complete procedure. Error might be somewhere else. Also the result of your select statement.

Comment: I second Ankit's comment. Are you sure your select is returning a result set? Because as-is, with a SELECT that returns row(s) your code should compile and run just fine.

Comment: Your output has a different number of columns than your code.  Interestingly, the difference is your output is missing the one column you're selecting from the `g_carto_municipios` table.  Are you certain your query contains the same join your code has and that the join isn't causing rows to be lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There was a sql statement that had not been committed by another user.